# Browser keeps being really rude to me today

Tags: windows, internet, browser, internet-explorer, malware

I've had this problem only once before, years ago.

I bought a new computer the other day and last night I visited a website which Google Chrome suspected was an insecure site. So I proceeded to view the page anyway (Stupid, I know... But I was curious), and all of a sudden the window closed and ever since, every few minutes either Google chrome or Internet Explorer keeps popping up with random websites, most of which are porn-related sites.

I have downloaded ZoneAlarm, IOBit 360, Eset Smart Security and none of them reported any problems. I still have the rube browser problem.

Can somebody please suggest any software/ways to fix this? (Other than to reformat please :))

Thank you :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Also Microsoft Security Essentials.

Comment: Yeah I love ms ess, but it failed me :( It was the first thing i installed when i turned this new pc on lol

Comment: Malwarebyte is my other option.

Comment: I like your other option. Sorry about the huge delay in marking an answer; I forgot what this site was called and couldn't find it in my history, and I only JUST remembered the name of this site (yes, i'm a bit slow) lol

Answer (score 6):

[Clamwin](http://www.clamwin.com/), [Malwarebytes](http://www.malwarebytes.org/) are the first two I would try.  They both are free at the starter levels and they dig pretty deep (especially Clamwin).  I have had really good experiences with these.  Also, Malwarebytes can scan a file, by right-clicking on the file and selecting scan.

Comment: +1 for Malwarebytes AntiMalware. Might want to suppliment it with a HijackThis scan

Answer (score 3):

I second malwarebytes. You need to run that over your computer, reboot and run it again to make sure everything is clean. Its always risky visiting dangerous sites like that and probably better to avoid on a machine you want to trust with personal information.

Answer (score 1):

As others have mentioned, MalwareBytes' Anti-Malware is pretty good at finding and removing all traces of really persistent malware.

Before I found out about MBAM, I used a program called [SDfix](http://www.bleepingcomputer.com/forums/topic131299.html).

If you still can't get rid of the nasties and don't want to reinstall, I highly recommend reading some articles and asking for help at [BleepingComputer](http://www.bleepingcomputer.com/forums/forum103.html).  They have a very good community of malware removal "experts."

Answer (score 0):

At the very least you need to know the name of the infection so you can find manual removal instructions. You might try an online scan like [this one](http://housecall.trendmicro.com/). I've seen good results with [Dr Web](http://download.drweb.com/demoreq/), too.

Answer (score 0):

You may also want to examine the browser's cookies.  Many websites deposit information onto your computer in the form of cookies.  If you don't care, delete them all.

Also, scan for malware too.

Answer (score 0):

If all else fails, reinstall, just thought I'd throw that out there...