# Chrome pop-up blocker fail?

Tags: google-chrome, blocking, popups

I have this problem since just a few days. I've been a heavy Chrome user for several years, but it never happened before: Sometimes absolutely uncalled for pop-ups appear, when I click something absolutely legit. It seems to happen at a very precise rate of two pop-ups every hour or so. The pop-ups are not very varied, it seems to be a fixed set of some 4-5 ads.

At first I thought I caught some malware, but after a full scan with Malwarebytes Anti-Malware, I found absolutely nothing. In addition the problem exists only with Chrome. When I use Firefox, this never ever happens.

What is even more puzzling is that it happens on both of my rigs and started on the same day. I have a removable storage that I dock to both of them and access one machine from the other via RDP, but still...

It seems this is a problem that others face too. See this [Google forum](https://productforums.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/chrome/j1wnkHZJlSo) and [here](https://superuser.com/questions/131065).
Could it be that the latest Chrome build is just acting up?

(Just in case it matters: I run Chrome version 24.0.1312.57 m on Win 7.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In fact I finally found out, what was the cause of my uninvited pop-ups. They appeared even if I clicked to upvote SE answers... which is definitely NOT a legit thing. It came from some third-party plug-ins, games more specifically, that I installed on Chrome... Since things get synchronized between my machines, this appeared *at the same time* on both machines making me even more confused. I'll just have to be more careful next time...

Answer (score 1):

If it's the same 5 ad's over and over and only in the one browser, you have *something*.
Things I would try:

- Install the free version of [Spybot](http://www.safer-networking.org/private/) and run a full scan and then an immunize. Don't forget to run as admin and close your browser's first.
- Check through Chrome's extensions and make sure you didn't collect a toolbar or some other suspicious extension.
- Install an Adblocking program like [AdBlock](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/adblock/gighmmpiobklfepjocnamgkkbiglidom?hl=en) if you haven't already.

Comment: Thanks! Seems that there was something after all and Malwarebytes Anti-Malware couldn't spot it. I think it was some tracking cookie. Anyway, now it's gone. `:)`

Answer (score 1):

You say that the pop-up appears **after** you click. It's not to blocker's duty to ensure that doesn't happen. It is supposed to block pop-ups that try to appear **without** you clicking. This is because there are a number of websites which need to show legit popups. Chrome can't distinguish between the good and the bad. So the general rule is that if the user clicks pop-ups are allowed.

Comment: That's possible but that doesn't sound very convincing to me. As I said, I've been using Chrome for years and the pop-up problem came really recently.

Comment: A number of developers have had this issue. Look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14272707/google-chrome-extension-how-to-generate-a-browser-action-without-clicking) for example. I hope you're convinced now. Rest assured you never had any malware just because of the popups

Comment: Not really, the point of a pop-up blocker is to stop the bad and let the good through. This is difficult, but modern blockers do fairly well at it.

Comment: “It's not to blocker's duty to ensure that doesn't happen.” It must not need a “blocker”. It is *the browser’s duty* to ensure that does not happen.

Comment: It is not so difficult to distinguish between the good and the bad. The rule I apply is simple. **All popups are bad, and must not appear.** Call me ayatollah.

Answer (score 0):

I have been having problems with popups with Chrome. I do not know why the built in blocker can not simply block !ALL! popups, and just simply do the same thing that Internet Explorer did(in IE, you simply click Ctl+left click if you want to open something that is normally being blocked.) I am an avid user of piratebay, the only thing I hate about their site is the popups. There is nothing you can do to stop them in Chrome, But with IE, not a single one is able to get through. I know without a doubt, 100% sure that I do not have any add-ons running, no spyware/malware on my machine. The only time that I have ever had a problem is with chrome. I am not going to bother using a 3rd party program to try to stop them, I will simply stop using chrome until they fix it. Its not only piratebay that I get the popups from, but its the best example that I can think of. PB is the only site that I ever go to, that without a doubt will always have a popup when I first open it. So to sum it up, for anyone wondering if there is a way to fix Chrome's popup problem; Not as of this time, not without using a 3rd party software. By the way, the version of Chrome I am running is ver.33.0.1750.154 It is up to date with the most recent version.

Answer (score 0):

It's probably an extension which is inadvertently disabling the popup blocker. For me I disabled the Plus HD 9.5 extension (turns Youtube videos to HD by default) and that fixed it.
Open Settings, click Extensions on right side,